# Is a quick search algorithm the same thing as a quick sort algorithm? [Computational Algorithms]

Tags: algorithm

This is just a question regarding terms for computational algorithms, the reference for quick search is: https://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node19.html

Can someone clarify if quick search is the same thing as quick sort?

I tried to google about quick search and only this https://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node19.html shows up as a reference.

Is there any other name or term for quick search that I might be unaware of?

Comment: You might be thinking of "quick select".

Comment: Are you looking for a string search algorithm? Or are you looking for an algorithm to select the largest (or smallest) `k` values from an array?

Comment: @JimMischel I need to do the Big O performance and what this means in terms of runtime, computational complexity and memory consumption. I know how to do all that and already coded  everything for such things. It is just a technical question about terminology as I never heard of the term "quick search".
I am just checking if it is called something else as there is no reference of such things in published papers and text books.

Comment: @JimMischelI know it is silly to ask this but i need to do a research about "quick search" and compare it's performance to brute force and reverse colussi, which I already know the difference for the 2 previous ones and have results/data for them but I can't find anything about "quick search".

Comment: Never heard of an algorithm called "quick search." But, considering that the site that has the quick search page (the one you identified) also has a page on reverse colussi, and they're both string search algorithms, I'd say use that one.

Comment: @JimMischel Just a heads up, I managed to find something about quick search:
https://www.di.ufpe.br/~paguso/courses/if767/bib/Sunday_1990.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is for sorting. Quick search seems to refer to some variation of the [Boyes moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) algorithm for searching a string in a larger text. They are definitely not the same thing.